# How can I render math formulas from StackExchange in my web browser?

Tags: discussion, mathjax

I would like to see maths formula in rendered form instead of code in Firefox. It is possible? For instance, in [this answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/28685/how-to-compute-acceleration-by-using-kinect-device-joint-positions/28687#28687), there is a formula:

```
$$(v_{x,i},v_{y,i},v_{z,i}) = \frac{(x_{i+1}-x_{i},y_{i+1}-y_{i},z_{i+1}-z_{i})}{t_{i+1}-t_{i}} \; .$$
```

I just see the formulas as code (`$$...`), and I would like to see interpreted formulas instead.

Comment: Related: http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/351/math-markdown-on-this-site

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe most people use MathJax / ChatJax. Give this page a read: http://www.math.ucla.edu/~robjohn/math/mathjax.html

You will find this bookmarklet which installs ChatJax into the current page:

```
javascript:(function(){if(window.MathJax===undefined){var%20script%20=%20document.createElement("script");script.type%20=%20"text/javascript";script.src%20=%20"http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML";var%20config%20=%20%27MathJax.Hub.Config({%27%20+%20%27extensions:%20["tex2jax.js"],%27%20+%20%27tex2jax:%20{%20inlineMath:%20[["$","$"],["\\\\\\\\\\\\(","\\\\\\\\\\\\)"]],%20displayMath:%20[["$$","$$"],["\\\\[","\\\\]"]],%20processEscapes:%20true%20},%27%20+%20%27jax:%20["input/TeX","output/HTML-CSS"]%27%20+%20%27});%27%20+%20%27MathJax.Hub.Startup.onload();%27;if%20(window.opera)%20{script.innerHTML%20=%20config}%20else%20{script.text%20=%20config}%20document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);(doChatJax=function(){window.setTimeout(doChatJax,1000);MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);})();}else{MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);}})();
```

Comment: Thanks ! I'd like to vote your answer up, but I can't right now !